# Move-AzureDeployment taking too long to swap servers?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to swap servers using Move-AzureDeployment cmdlet by running it in my powershell. It seems to take around 4 mins for it to swap from staging to production. Thats 4 mins of downtime and it's not really acceptable. When I swap the servers manually from the Azure Portal it happens almost instantaneously.

I was wondering why it takes longer using the cmdlet and what can I do to fix this issue because I want to be able to swap my Staging and Production Servers using powershell.

Here is my powershell Script:

```
  try
{   
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

Write-Host "Deploying build build no. $env:build_number to $_serviceName"

#import azure cmdlets module
Write-Host "Importing azure service management modules (i.e for the old portal)"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1"

Write-Host "Started Command for Switching Slots"
#Switch slots from Staging to Production
Move-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $_serviceName
Write-Host "Finished Command for Switching Slots"


#make sure deployment is in running state
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"
$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() #declare stopwatch
while (($deployment.Status -ne "running") -and ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours -lt 2)) #running the loop for a maximum of 2 hours
{   
    Write-Host "wait 5 seconds before trying again" 
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
    Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"        
}

#make sure all roles are in ready state
$nonReadyInstances = (Get-AzureDeployment $_serviceName -Slot $_slotName).RoleInstanceList | Where-Object { $_.InstanceStatus -ne "ReadyRole" } | ft -Property RoleName, InstanceName, InstanceStatus
$nonReadyInstances
$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() #declare stopwatch
while (($nonReadyInstances -ne $null) -and ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours -lt 2)) #running the loop for a maximum of 2 hours
{
    Write-Host "wait 5 seconds before trying again" 
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $nonReadyInstances = (Get-AzureDeployment $_serviceName -Slot $_slotName).RoleInstanceList | Where-Object { $_.InstanceStatus -ne "ReadyRole" }
    $nonReadyInstances
}

#output deployment id   
#$deploymentid = Check-Deployment -serviceName $_serviceName -slotName $_slotName
#Write-Host "Deployed to $_serviceName with deployment id $deploymentid and slot $_slotName"
    exit 0

  }
catch [System.Exception]
  {
Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
exit 1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding a the swap between staging slot and production is a VIP  swap as they are both running. Microsoft says you shouldn't see any downtime on the site/app itself. Requests will still hit the old production server until the  change is complete. Are you seeing downtime on the site during the swap?

Comment: I talked to Microsoft Support Rep and he mentioned although they advertise the VIP swap as a no downtime operation, but in reality there is some downtime associated with it and that's what I was seeing. Just wondering how we can get around this?